# Formatting table to look nice

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
#include "cmath"
#include "iomanip"

std::string name, item_name;
double loan_amount, annual_interest_rate;
int number_of_years;

double rate;
int number_of_payments;
double monthly_payments, total_amount_paid, total_interest_paid;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Welcome to the Monthly Payment Program." << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Item being financed: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, item_name);
    std::cout << "Enter the loan amount: ";
    std::cin >> loan_amount;
    std::cout << "Enter the annual interest rate (in percentage): ";
    std::cin >> annual_interest_rate;
    std::cout << "Enter the duration of the loan in years: ";
    std::cin >> number_of_years;

    rate = annual_interest_rate / (12 * 100);
    number_of_payments = number_of_years * 12;
    monthly_payments = (rate * std::pow((1 + rate), number_of_payments))/(std::pow((1 + rate), number_of_payments) - 1);
    total_amount_paid = number_of_payments * monthly_payments;
    total_interest_paid = total_amount_paid - loan_amount;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    int width = 30;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << "Item being financed: "  << item_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << std::setprecision(3) << "Monthly Interest Rate: "  << rate << "%" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << "Number of Payments: "   << number_of_payments << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << std::setprecision(2) << "Monthly Payment: "  << "$ " << monthly_payments << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << std::setprecision(2) << "Total Amount Paid: "  << "$ " <<total_amount_paid << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(width) << std::setprecision(2) << "Interest Paid: " << "$ " <<total_interest_paid << std::endl;
}
```

When I run the code it looks like this

Welcome to the Monthly Payment Program.

```
Enter your name: John Doe
Item being financed: Bass
Enter the loan amount: 15000
Enter the annual interest rate (in percentage): 8
Enter the duration of the loan in years: 3

Name:                         John Doe
Item being financed:          Bass
Monthly Interest Rate:        0.00667%
Number of Payments:           36
Monthly Payment:              $ 0.031
Total Amount Paid:            $ 1.1
Interest Paid:                $ -1.5e+04
```

I don't care that the calculations are all wrong, however, I need it to look like this

[image: layout expected]

I have tried playing around with left, setw, and cannot seem to get it to look right.

How can I achieve the example?

Comment: Insert `std::setw(10)` and `std::right` where appropriate.

Comment: Unrelated: `#include "string"` - you want `#include <string>`. The #include ""` format is for your own headers.

Answer (score 3):

Iomanip functions are not permanent. They need to be called before every output.

Example:

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw( width ) 
          << "Interest Paid: "
          << "$ " 
          << std::right << std::fixed << std::setw( width ) << std::setprecision( 2 )  
          << total_interest_paid
          << std::endl;
```

Comment: This does **not** fix OP's problem. Give it a try and you'll see it's harder than it looks ;)

Comment: Well, yes, for one row. Try with multiple rows now :) Anyway, reverted my downvote, this example can lead OP to a satisfaying answer.

Comment: @YSC For multiple rows the library fmt would be more appropriate.